# Guake terminal has space left at the top

Tags: guake

When starting the Guake terminal in 13.04, there is a space of 1-2 cms left at the top. i.e THe guake terminal top border is 1-2 cms below the screen top edge.

How can I fix this as it was working perfectly in 12.10.

***Per the selected answer, its now moved to the top okay, but does anyone have any ideas on the two minor lines at the sides? ( :) It keeps bothering me)***

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve the problem by making gravity go upwards. No, seriously ;)

You need to do a simple change to the file `/usr/share/guake/guake.glade`. Open that file with your favorite text editor and look for the line that says

```
<property name="gravity">static</property>
```

Change that line, so that it says

```
<property name="gravity">north</property>
```

Save the file, restart Guake and the gap should be gone.

Comment: Thanks Henning! Defying the laws of gravity did essentially solve my problem. ;) ;)   Now guake does snap to the top.. but... there are narrow (not more than 1 mm wide) lines at both the left and right side of the guake terminal. I guess the guake terminal is not stretching to the entire width of the screen.

Comment: I see those lines as well, but at least in my eyes they're so small that I wont invest time to get rid of them ;)

Comment: Can anyone else help me get rid of the narrow lines to the left and right of guake terminal?

Comment: This stopped to work in Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I still have the problem, so I file a [bug report](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/920). 12px down, only on one of the screens.

Answer (score 1):

guake glade causes terminal goes back to menubar, i have did it with nano /usr/bin/guake

find this and add window_rect.y = 25 before return

```
def get_final_window_rect(self):
        """Gets the final size of the main window of guake. The height
        is the window_height property, width is window_width and the
        horizontal alignment is given by window_alignment.
        """
        screen = self.window.get_screen()
        height = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_height'))
        width = 100
        halignment = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_halignment'))

        # get the rectangle just from the first/default monitor in the
        # future we might create a field to select which monitor you
        # wanna use
        window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(0)
        total_width = window_rect.width
        window_rect.height = window_rect.height * height / 100
        window_rect.width = window_rect.width * width / 100

        if width < total_width:
            if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
                window_rect.x = (total_width - window_rect.width) / 2
            elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
                window_rect.x = 0
            elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
                window_rect.x = total_width - window_rect.width
        window_rect.y = 25 # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
        return window_rect
```

Comment: I tried this with =25 and =26 values, but no changes?

Comment: It does seems tobe the right place to edit. Can anyone help me with the correct values? What is the window_rect.y property value unit? Is it percentage or something?

Comment: I tried with some other values as well...but nothing happens... is this file deprecated?

Comment: neither work for me